# How to Update document which is returned as Output in mongodb find using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I first want to query for latest document in mongoose. Then, I want to update my document based on some condition, if Timestamp field is older 15 minutes, I want to create new instance and pass `req.body`, otherwise, I only want to update my query result with `req.body`...

I have written own schema method `tsFromID()` to check if Timestamp is older 15 minutes, but I don't know how to update a returned result from a mongoose **query:**

```
exports.updateFlexPotenzial15minData = function(req, res, next) {
  const minID = +req.params.demo_id * 1000000;
  const maxID = (+req.params.demo_id + 1) * 1000000;
  FlexPotenzial.find({
    _id: {
      $gte: minID,
      $lt: maxID
    }
  }).sort({
    'createdAt': -1
  }).limit(1).exec(function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else if (result.tsFromID()) {
      var newFP = new FlexPotenzial(req.body);
      newFP.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(400);
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          res.status(200);
          res.json({
            message: 'Neues Flexpotenzial erzeugt, da älter als 15 min!'
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      result.update(update with req.body) < --How to update my returned result ?

    }    
  })
}
```

If it's not possible to update a returned document instance , how would I do it otherwise?

Comment: use findOneAndUpdate method

Comment: makes no sense, I cannot do a check inside findOneAndUpdate method, otherweise, I would have to query again and search for the last value, and then check for its timestamp, and I am again stuck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongoose update query like this

```
...
...
else {
  FlexPotenzial.findByIdAndUpdate(result._id, req.body, (err, result) => {
    // do whatever you want
  })
}
```

Comment: I dont have any id to look for, I want explicitly look for the latest item of some id-range, and after I have retrieved the last document, I would like to update it based on some condition, I cannot do this in findByIdAndUpdate.. guys is this so hard to understand?

Comment: ok sorry I think I now understand, I just do a second query and pass the _id of my returned result.. makes sense thanks..